# Update-Package : Package 'WebActivator' is not found

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, visual-studio-2015, package-managers

Error preventing me from updating nuget packages
I have not updated for a while but this has me really stuck
This was installed as part of breeze.
The reference is intact
Not sure what i can do from here.
Any help appreciated before I take on a low level hunt for the cause.

Answer (score 0):

As in [docs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebActivatorEx/):

```
PM> Install-Package WebActivatorEx
```

A package that allows other packages to execute some startup code in web apps. This package should be used over the older WebActivator, which was not strong named.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I have tried this.
WebActivatorEx is actually installed but I cannot Update my packages because of this error.

Comment: You need to delete WebActivator package first. It is replaced by WebActivatorEx completly.

Comment: interesting I switched back to VS2013 and it all updates fine. So now im really confused. Seems like a bug in nuget VS2015
But i will try that. Cheers